# Font Management Problem

Tags: fonts, xetex, memoir, fontspec

I'm trying to re-create a title in Peter Wilson's examples, ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf I downloaded the free font Bergamo and also bought the font Mona Lisa FS and installed them but somehow I am not able to access these fonts. It seems that **5bp** and **5ml** is not the correct way to access them. I see the fonts are installed on the Font Book (Mac) but how can access them?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=6.875in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\newlength{\drop}% for my convenience
%% select a (FontSite) font by its font family ID
\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%% if you don’t have the FontSite fonts either \renewcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{}
%% or use your own choice of family.
%% select a (TeX Font) font by its font family ID
\newcommand*{\TXfont}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%% Generic publisher’s logo
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
\newcommand*{\titleAT}{\begingroup% Anatomy of a Typeface
\FSfont{5bp} % FontSite Bergamo (Bembo)
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\drop}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{2pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par
\vspace{0.5\drop}
\centering
\textcolor{red}{
{\FSfont{5ml} % FontSite Mona Lisa
\Huge Lectures}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\FSfont{5ml}
\Large On}\\[0.75\baselineskip]
{\FSfont{5ml}
\Huge Microeconomics}}\par
\vspace{0.25\drop}
\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par
\vspace{\drop}
{\Large \scshape S\'ergio O. Parreiras }\par
\vfill
{\large \textcolor{red}{\plogo}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large\scshape the publisher}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\titleAT
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\mainmatter
BOOK TEXT GOES HERE
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/ for the support files — but today you’re better off using `luatex` or `xetex` with the `ttf` versions of the fonts, if that’s what you have.

Comment: @Thérèse: Merci: I do not have the 500 fonts CD. I just got these fonts individually and I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Then you can write something like `\newfontface\monal{ITC Mona Lisa Recut}` (or whatever your font is called), and where the orignal has `\FSfont{5ml}`, just write `\monal`.

Comment: @Thérèse: Thanks again, it worked. *Fontspec* package is easier than I assumed. Please consider making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I no longer have the Mona Lisa font, but here’s an example of modifying the code for fonts other than those Peter Wilson used. The code is simpler with `fontspec`:

```
% xetex or luatex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}
\newfontface\bmb{Bembo Book MT Pro}[Numbers=OldStyle]% or use \setmainfont if the main matter will be in Bembo
\newfontface\had{LTC Hadriano Pro Stone Cut}
\usepackage[a5paper,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\newlength{\drop}
%% Generic publisher’s logo
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
\newcommand*{\titleAT}{\begingroup% Anatomy of a Typeface
\bmb
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\drop}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{2pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par
\vspace{0.5\drop}
\centering
\textcolor{red}{
{\had\Huge Lectures}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\had\Large on}\\[0.75\baselineskip]
{\had\Huge Microeconomics}}\par
\vspace{0.25\drop}
\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par
\vspace{\drop}
{\Large\scshape Sérgio O. Parreiras }\par
\vfill
{\large\textcolor{red}{\plogo}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large\scshape the publisher}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titleAT
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\mainmatter
BOOK TEXT GOES HERE
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code]

The idea is simply to remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and, in place of the macro `\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}`, to use the `\newfontface` command from `fontspec`.